# Report in Mysql - man sub tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables that have the following type of data:

```
articleid, userid, date purchased

userid, provstate, country
```

I want to generate a report that looks like this:

```
Count   Article Id    Date          Country    Prov/State
  3          1        April 2013     Canada       Ontatio
  1          1        April 2013     Canada       PEI
  4          1        April 2013     USA          Maine
```

Data should be ordered by date ascending and alphabetical by country and province
and grouped by articleid ascending.

So it would basically display all info about article 1, then article 2, etc.

Anybody have any good suggestions?

My attempts have revolved around this basic query:

```
SELECT COUNT( articleid ) , articleid, DATE_FORMAT( date_purchased,  "%M %Y" ) , country, provstate
FROM story_history, user_info
WHERE story_history.userid = user_info.userid
```

and futz with ORDER BY AND GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group by the fields you are not aggregating (articleid, DATE_FORMAT( date_purchased,"%M %Y" ) , country, provstate ) and order by he fields you want to order by (date , country,  Province)

```
SELECT COUNT( articleid ) , articleid, DATE_FORMAT( date_purchased,  "%M %Y" ) `date` , country, provstate
FROM story_history, user_info
WHERE story_history.userid = user_info.userid
group by articleid, DATE_FORMAT( date_purchased,  "%M %Y" ) , country, provstate
order by `date` , country  Province
```